# Undefined citation in Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

I use the natbib package for my work and all my citations are working fine, except this one:

```
@article{tobin58,
author    = {Tobin, James},
title     = {Liquidity Preference as Behavior Toward Risk},
journal   = {Review of Economic Studies},
volume   = {25},
number   = {2},
pages    = {pp. 65--86},
year      = {1958}
}
```

In the bbl this translates to:

```
\harvarditem{Tobin}{1958}{tobin58}
Tobin, J.  \harvardyearleft 1958\harvardyearright , `Liquidity preference as
behavior toward risk', {\em Review of Economic Studies} {\bf 25}(2),~pp.
65--86.
```

And the error I receive:

```
Package Natbib warning: citation 'tobin58' on page 5 undefined on input line 196
```

I think the the setting of the environment is correct as other citations do work, nevertheless I also receive 2 errors:

```
File ended while scanning use of \harvarditem
```

I get this error on line `\bibliography{BibTeX1}`

```
LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}
```

I get this error on line `\end{document}`

```
\clearpage
\bibliography{BibTeX1}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\clearpage
\appendix
\section{First Appendix}
Appendix
\end{document}
```

The syntax of my citation is identical to the working ones, I really can't find any syntax errors.

Could you help me please? Do I need to provide you more information?

Comment: A full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) would be of great help. Of especial interest would be: How do you call `natbib` (options etc.)? Is there any other package that might interfere with `natbib`? What cite commands do you use? For what it's worth, you might want to have a look at [natbib: use the harvard referencing system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102937/35864) and [`har2nat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/har2nat).

Comment: On another note, you should not put `pp.` or `p.` manually into the `pages` field, BibTeX and the like can do that for you automatically. Unfortunately, `agsm` uses [obsolete font commands (`\bf`, `\em`)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516/35864), so it might not be the best choice after all.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Given that you're using the `agsm` bibliography style, are you also loading the `harvard` citation management package? If you prefer to use the `natbib` citation management package instead, you should load the `har2nat` package as well -- and not load the `harvard` package at all. This point is also addressed in @moewe's comment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what the source of the error is that you're getting. Maybe it's the fact that you're using the `natbib` citation management package along with `agsm`, which is a bibliography style provide by the `harvard` citation management system. It's best not to mix-and-match citation management packages and bibliography styles. If you do need to use `natbib` *and* `agsm`, you should also load the `har2nat` package (but not the `harvard` package as well!).

Anyway, assuming that the `tobin58` bibliographic entry is stored in a file called `tobin58.bib`, the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib,har2nat}
%%\usepackage{harvard}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}

\citet{tobin58}
%%\citeasnoun{tobin58}

\bibliography{tobin58}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

If you prefer, comment out the natbib-related instructions and uncomment the two harvard-related instructions. By the way, if you remove the "pp. " from the `pages` field of the bibliographic entry, it will also disappear from the typeset output.

Incidentally, this is what the `.bbl` file produced by the MWE looks like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{xx}

\harvarditem{Tobin}{1958}{tobin58}
Tobin, J.  \harvardyearleft 1958\harvardyearright , `Liquidity preference as
  behavior toward risk', {\em Review of Economic Studies} {\bf 25}(2),~pp.
  65--86.

\end{thebibliography}
```