# BibTex Error - .bbl' not created by bib latex

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I've been trying to use this post to create a bibliography ([natbib: use the harvard referencing system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102937/natbib-use-the-harvard-referencing-system)) but am receiving the error `.bbl' not created by bib latex.`

My `.tex file`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents,hyperref}

\title{Assignment \#1}
\author{}
\date{March 29, 2014}


\begin{filecontents}{bibtest.bib}
@online{zappone2009supermarketduopoly,
author = {Zappone, C.},
title = {Supermarket duopoly blamed for soaring food prices},
year = {2009}, 
url = {http://www.smh.com.au/business/supermarket-duopoly-blamed-for-soaring-food-    prices-20091109-i3tn.html},
urldate = {2014-29-03}
}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bibtest}


\begin{document}


\maketitle    

\section*{Question 1}

\subsection*{Woolworths}

\textit{Core Business:}

\parencite{zappone2009supermarketduopoly}.




\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Would anyone know what the problem is?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: On first sight, you just have to do another run of `biber`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `.bbl` files created by a normal BibTeX run and a Biber run (or BibTeX with `biblatex`) are completely different and they are not compatible with each other.

Surely you've used a file where a "normal" bibliography was used and afterwards you've switched to `biblatex`.

That's why `biblatex` is complaining that the `.bbl` file has not been created by it.

The solution is to delete the `.bbl` file and run pdflatex and Biber again.

This is the contents of the `.bbl` file generated by `biblatex` with Biber from your bibliography:

```
% $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex bbl format version 2.3 $
% Do not modify the above lines!
%
% This is an auxiliary file used by the 'biblatex' package.
% This file may safely be deleted. It will be recreated by
% biber as required.
%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \sortlist{entry}{nyt}
    \entry{zappone2009supermarketduopoly}{online}{}
      \name{labelname}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=af62e8eb39454b026c19a85900defef2}{Zappone}{Z\bibinitperiod}{C.}{C\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{uniquename=0,hash=af62e8eb39454b026c19a85900defef2}{Zappone}{Z\bibinitperiod}{C.}{C\bibinitperiod}{}{}{}{}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{af62e8eb39454b026c19a85900defef2}
      \strng{fullhash}{af62e8eb39454b026c19a85900defef2}
      \field{sortinit}{Z}
      \field{labelyear}{2009}
      \field{datelabelsource}{}
      \field{labeltitle}{Supermarket duopoly blamed for soaring food prices}
      \field{title}{Supermarket duopoly blamed for soaring food prices}
      \field{urlday}{03}
      \field{urlmonth}{29}
      \field{urlyear}{2014}
      \field{year}{2009}
      \verb{url}
      \verb http://www.smh.com.au/business/supermarket-duopoly-blamed-for-soaring-food-%20prices-20091109-i3tn.html
      \endverb
    \endentry
  \endsortlist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

As you can see, it doesn't even contain the `thebibliography` environment...

As a side note, when using `biblatex`, it is recommended to use

```
\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}
```

instead of

```
\bibliography{bibtest}
```

The latter works for compatibility only.

Comment: Thank you Karl. When I run the my `.tex` file in `TexWorks`, I am running it with the options - `pdflatex + MakeIndex + BibTex`. However, no `.bbl` file is being created. The program runs without error, but the output after `\parentcite{zappone2009supermarketduopoly}` is just `zappone2009supermarketduopoly`. If I initially run `BibTex` first, it creates an empty `.bbl` file.

Comment: @Giri See this thread for configuring TeXWorks to run Biber: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69705/27635

Answer (score 5):

You have to write `\addbibresource{bibtest.bib}` (with the .bib extension) instead of `\bibliography{bibtest}`(without the extension).

Comment: While `\bibliography{filename}` is generally deprecated in favour of `\addbibresource{filename.bib}`, the former does still work as advertised (if used correctly, but then, one also has to use `\addbibresource` properly).

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, I just had the same problem: no bbl file being created. The default log messages weren't any help. I used a program called "rubber", which showed me I had used an undefined command in one place. After fixing that, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bbl file if you click on the "log and other files" icon next to compile, recompile icon just above the pdf viewer. Then you can scroll down, and at the bottom you have a "log and other file" icon/button, you can select it to download the bbl file. Or just delete the cached files using the icon next and the re-run the latex file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please see that not all people here use overleaf. You are describing an function of overleaf and it was not mentioned in the question of the OP that overleaf is used ... I guess what you describe is not a solution for the OP ...